# What is PL/SQL Hibernate jar list?

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jar, plsql

For my personal projects, I am using Hibernate in order to connect a Java Dynamic Web Application with a MySQL Database. Here is the list of the jars I am using:

- antlr-2.7.6rc1.jar
- asm-attrs.jar
- asm.jar
- cglib-2.1.3.jar
- commons-collections-2.1.1.jar
- commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
- dom4j-1.6.1.jar
- ehcache-1.1.jar
- hibernate3.jar
- jta.jar
- log4j-1.2.11.jar
- mysql-connector-java-3.0.17-ga-bin.jar

At work, things are slightly different since we are currently using PL/SQL instead of MySQL. My questions are:

- Which jar should I use to replace **mysql-connector-java-3.0.17-ga-bin.jar**?
- where I can find find this jar?
- Should I add/remove/replace a jar from the list above?

For your information :

- I am not using a Hibernate plugin in my app.
- I am using xml files instead of JPA annotations for Hibernate mapping.

I hope I was clear,

Thanks in advance for your help,

Kind regards.

Comment: PL/SQL is a language. It's not a database. If you're using Oracle, then google for "Oracle JDBC driver". Same for all the other databases.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you're right. I downloaded the ojdbc.jar (X for the java version) from the Oracle Website.

Thanks,

Omar.